# Is every graph the center of some other graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

The [center of a graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_center) $G$ is the set of vertices that minimize the largest
distance to vertices in $G$, e.g., in the graph below, that radius is $4$:

 
 
 
 
 
[image: GraphCenter50]

Define the center $C$ as the subgraph of $G$ induced
by those vertices.
I seek to learn constraints on $C$. Is it the case that every graph $C$ is the center of some graph $G$? Or are there constraints on the possible structures of $C$?

---

(**Addendum** *5Mar14*.)
Joe Malkevitch asked (personal communication):

> Is every plane graph the center of some other plane graph?

Comment: How about the following construction:  Introduce two new vertices $A$ and $B$.  Connect all the vertices in $C$ to $A$; and connect all the vertices in $C$ to $B$.  From $A$ draw a long line with many vertices on it (the line doesn't have any other edges to $C$), and  similarly from $B$ draw a long line with many vertices on it (same number of vertices as the line from $A$).  Now if I understand your question correctly, I think $C$ is the center of this new graph.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan:  I thought it would take one more step to connect $A$ to the end of $B$, and so $A$ would not be in the center; and the same for $B$.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Lucia: oh, my apologies. I thought you had drawn an edge from $A$ to $B$ for some reason. Yes, I think this works.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Great; thanks for checking!

Comment: @Lucia: Beautiful construction! I will accept that if you make it an answer. How short can the long paths of many vertices be?

Comment: @Joseph: it just needs to be longer than the diameter of the graph, right?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm just copying my comment above, as it seems to answer the question.  For any graph $C$ there exists a graph for which this is the center.  Introduce two new vertices $A$ and $B$. Connect all the vertices in $C$ to $A$; and connect all the vertices in $C$ to $B$. From $A$ draw a long line with many vertices on it (the line doesn't have any other edges to $C$), and similarly from $B$ draw a long line with many vertices on it (same number of vertices as the line from $A$, and this number is larger than the maximum length between two vertices in $C$).  Now the vertices in $C$ form the center of this new graph.

Comment: You don't actually need "long line"s of vertices, you can just attach another vertex to each of A and B. $\hspace{.6 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer: You're absolutely right! Nice observation.